# Run as a different user access denied: How to set-up a "super-user" with access to everything?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, administrator, accessibility

I am using "run as a different user" to run an application on Windows 10. The application is started smoothly; however, I am not able to do anything with it because whatever I click it says "access denied". I am on an administrator account.

Any solution?

Detail: The "other use" successfully run the application and created a folder on my hard drive. However, I cannot access the folder. When I double click it, it says "access denied".

Answer (score 0):

You are an Administrator (as per above).

When you run as a Different User (that needs admin credentials), then the different user must be a member of the Administrators Group.

I am assuming you want the application to run properly in the other (different) user.

Comment: I'll give a try... I add the ADM privilege for the "other user" but still I cannot access any of "other user's" file

Comment: When you run as a different user, your application uses the credential properties of that different user.